# Can this multi-nested query be optimized?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of over 100k records, and this query, for 300 users (uid), is taking up to 30 seconds to complete (in my Drupal website).

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|id  |uid |lesson_id |game_id |score |duration |date       |
------------------------------------------------------------
|1   |144 |65        |0       |70    |12303    |1392479414 |
|2   |145 |65        |0       |80    |12001    |1392474564 |
|3   |145 |65        |1       |60    |11056    |1392479467 |
|4   |144 |66        |1       |60    |12001    |1392479854 |
|... |... |...       |...     |...   |...      |...        |
|... |... |...       |...     |...   |...      |...        |
|... |... |...       |...     |...   |...      |...        |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm trying to get for each uid:

for each lesson_id where game_id is 0:

the average of all best scores, the total duration, a count

for each lesson_id for each game_id (> 0):

a sum of all best scores, a sum of all the first scores, the total duration

```
SELECT 
q1.*, 
q2.*, 
q3.* 
FROM (
    SELECT 
    SUM(sq.max_score) / 71 AS avg_max_scores, 
    SUM(sq.total_duration) AS sum_total_duration, 
    SUM(1) AS assessment_count
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        up.*, 
        MAX(up.score) AS max_score, 
        SUM(up.duration) AS total_duration
        FROM cdu_user_progress up
        WHERE 
        (up.uid = '145') AND 
        (up.lesson_id IN  ('65', '66', '67')) AND 
        (up.score > '-1')
        GROUP BY up.lesson_id, up.game_id
    ) sq
    WHERE  (sq.game_id = '0') 
) q1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    SUM(sq.max_score) AS sum_max_scores_games, 
    SUM(sq.total_duration) AS sum_total_duration_games
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        up.*, 
        MAX(up.score) AS max_score, 
        SUM(up.duration) AS total_duration
        FROM cdu_user_progress up
        WHERE 
        (up.uid = '145') AND 
        (up.lesson_id IN  ('65', '66', '67')) 
        AND (up.score > '-1')
        GROUP BY up.lesson_id, up.game_id
    ) sq
    WHERE  (sq.game_id > '0') 
) q2
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
    SUM(q.first_score) / 71 AS avg_first_scores
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        sq.max_date AS max_date, 
        up.score AS first_score
        FROM (
            SELECT 
            up.*, 
            MIN(up.date) AS first_date, 
            MAX(up.date) AS max_date
            FROM cdu_user_progress up
            WHERE 
            (up.uid = '145') AND 
            (up.lesson_id IN  ('65', '66', '67')) AND 
            (up.score > '-1') AND 
            (up.game_id = '0')
            GROUP BY up.lesson_id
        ) sq
        LEFT OUTER JOIN cdu_user_progress up ON up.lesson_id = sq.lesson_id AND up.game_id = sq.game_id AND up.date = sq.first_date
    ) q
) q3
```

Explain output:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys                                           key                                                     key_len ref                     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY <derived2>  system  NULL                                                    NULL                                                    NULL    NULL                    1    
1   PRIMARY <derived4>  system  NULL                                                    NULL                                                    NULL    NULL                    1    
1   PRIMARY <derived6>  system  NULL                                                    NULL                                                    NULL    NULL                    1    
6   DERIVED <derived7>  ALL     NULL                                                    NULL                                                    NULL    NULL                    71   
7   DERIVED <derived8>  ALL     NULL                                                    NULL                                                    NULL    NULL                    71   
7   DERIVED up          ref     cdu_user_progress(lesson_id, game_id)                   cdu_user_progress(lesson_id, game_id)                   8       sq.lesson_id,sq.game_id 7    
8   DERIVED up          range   cdu_user_progress(uid, lesson_id, level, game_id, ...   cdu_user_progress(uid, lesson_id, level, game_id, ...   12      NULL                    628     Using where
4   DERIVED <derived5>  ALL     NULL                                                    NULL                                                    NULL    NULL                    90      Using where
5   DERIVED up          ref     cdu_user_progress(uid, lesson_id, level, game_id, ...   cdu_user_progress(uid, lesson_id, level, game_id, ...   4                               678     Using where
2   DERIVED <derived3>  ALL     NULL                                                    NULL                                                    NULL    NULL                    90      Using where
3   DERIVED up          ref     cdu_user_progress(uid, lesson_id, level, game_id, ...   cdu_user_progress(uid, lesson_id, level, game_id, ...   4                               678     Using where
```

Comment: You should really decide whether you are using MySQL or Oracle and tag the question appropriately.

Comment: have you checked the explain plan?    [Explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Avoid nesting request in SQL, it kills performances.**
If you have no other choice make some temporary tables with **indexes**, will be much faster.

Like :

```
CREATE TABLE pop AS (
    SELECT 
    up.*, 
    MAX(up.score) AS max_score, 
    SUM(up.duration) AS total_duration
    FROM cdu_user_progress up
    WHERE 
    (up.uid = '145') AND 
    (up.lesson_id IN  ('65', '66', '67')) AND 
    (up.score > '-1')
    GROUP BY up.lesson_id, up.game_id);
```

Then :

```
CREATE INDEX index_pop ON pop (game_id);
```

So your request will look sommething like :

```
SELECT q1.*, q2.*, q3.* 
 FROM (
   SELECT 
     SUM(sq.max_score) / 71 AS avg_max_scores, 
     SUM(sq.total_duration) AS sum_total_duration, 
     SUM(1) AS assessment_count
     FROM pop sq
     WHERE  (sq.game_id = '0') 
 ) q1
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 
   SUM(sq.max_score) AS sum_max_scores_games, 
   SUM(sq.total_duration) AS sum_total_duration_games
   FROM pop sq
   WHERE  (sq.game_id > '0') 
 ) q2
 INNER JOIN (
   SELECT 
   SUM(q.first_score) / 71 AS avg_first_scores
   FROM (
    SELECT 
    sq.max_date AS max_date, 
    up.score AS first_score
    FROM (
        SELECT 
        up.*, 
        MIN(up.date) AS first_date, 
        MAX(up.date) AS max_date
        FROM cdu_user_progress up
        WHERE 
        (up.uid = '145') AND 
        (up.lesson_id IN  ('65', '66', '67')) AND 
        (up.score > '-1') AND 
        (up.game_id = '0')
        GROUP BY up.lesson_id
    ) sq
    LEFT OUTER JOIN cdu_user_progress up ON up.lesson_id = sq.lesson_id AND up.game_id = sq.game_id AND up.date = sq.first_date
  ) q
) q3;
```

You could reduce your request execution time by a lot more, if you cut your request in more tables.
Just remember to drop them after if you don't want to keep them